# Pass enum value in remoting method

Tags: visualforce, javascript-remoting

I'm calling a remoting method from javascript. The method expects a custom class with one of the fields of type `ConnectApi.MarkupType`.

While sending a string value for this field, I'm getting an error `Unexpected type for Controller.methos(CustomClass)`

How do I send the enum value from frontend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing the string representation - the name - should work:

```
private static Map<String, ConnectApi.MarkupType> MT_MAP {
    get {
        if (MT_MAP == null) {
            MT_MAP = new Map<String, ConnectApi.MarkupType>();
            for (ConnectApi.MarkupType v : ConnectApi.MarkupType.values()) {
                MT_MAP.put(v.name(), v);
            }
        }
        return MT_MAP;
    }
    set;
}

@AuraEnabled
public static void methos(String mts) {

    ConnectApi.MarkupType mt = MT_MAP.get(mts);

    ...
}
```

Comment: It's oddly specific that you can return an enum value but not accept an enum parameter, despite the fact it compiles.